# Java, Take a number from a string, and assign it to a separate Variable - Java

Tags: java, string, int

Okay, so I'm making a program and I want to take an input for a license plate # (Numbers and Letters) and what I'm looking to do is, take the input in one line, and be able to separate the Numbers and Letters in the input into two different variables, one Int and one String.

```
public class CarRental {
   public static String model;
   public static String plate;
   public static int platenum;
   public static void main(String[] args){
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Car Model:");
      model = input.nextLine();
      System.out.println("License Plate: ");
      plate = input.nextLine();
        ...
```

I want to assign the numbers from the input to the int and keep the characters in the string plate?
What would be the way I can do this?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does # mean "number"? If so, why not use "number"? It's only 5 chars longer, and makes your question readable.

Comment: Please show us an example - it will be much clearer how your input looks like

Comment: And also give what you expect as output for the example input, because that is not clear either.

Comment: So, you're asking for free help, but are too lazy to formulate an intelligible question. Hmmm. I see. I won't help you then. Plonk!

Comment: There is a fundamental difference between asking to take a '#' from a string, and asking to take a number, and both of these are very common types of tasks in Java.  He wasn't being rude, he was asking for clarification to a poorly worded question.

Comment: Alright, wasn't aware. Pardon the foul mouth there. Still a beginner...sorry bout that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You usually use regex for these types of things. Have a look at Java regex (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)

Answer (score 1):

Use this: 
[How to split a string between letters and digits (or between digits and letters)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270784/how-to-split-a-string-between-letters-and-digits-or-between-digits-and-letters)

Like this for example:

```
licensePlate = "JGY7433";

licensePlateLetters = licensePlate.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)")[0];
licensePlateNumber = Integer.parseInt(licensePlate.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)")[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using regular expressions:

```java
String s = "A1B2C3";
List<String> letters = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Pattern pLetters=Pattern.compile("([A-Za-z])"), pNumbers=Pattern.compile("(\\d)");
Matcher mLetters=pLetters.matcher(s), mNumbers=pNumbers.matcher(s);
while (mLetters.find()) { letters.add(mLetters.group(1)); }
while (mNumbers.find()) { numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(mNumbers.group(1))); }
System.out.println("OK: letters=" + letters); // => OK: letters=[A, B, C]
System.out.println("OK: numbers=" + numbers); // => OK: numbers=[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks, Its a bit complex for me, but thanks for taking the time.