# JAVA regex to add white space between character and number

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a java regex to add white space between character and number. I tried few of them but its not working.

For example: This string "FR3456", I would like this to be converted to "FR 3456".

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Showing us the regex that you used to attempt to solve this would go a long way into helping; we could potentially build off of that.

Comment: This might help you -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270784/how-to-split-a-string-between-letters-and-digits-or-between-digits-and-letters

Answer (score 11):

You can add a space between non-digit and digit using [**Positive Lookbehind & Lookahead**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
System.out.println("FR3456".replaceAll("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)"," "));
```

Here

```
\D  A non-digit: [^0-9]
\d  A digit: [0-9]
```

for more info have a look at [Java Regex Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

---

Or use `(?<=[^0-9])(?=[0-9])`

Here is [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/jA8hH9/2)

Pattern explanation:

```
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
    [^0-9]                   any character except: '0' to '9'
  )                        end of look-behind
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
    [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: How to get results like `FR 3 4 5 6` ?

Comment: Thanks for explanation use `(?<=\S)(?=\d)` to get results like `FR 3 4 5 6`,

Comment: how to get result like **765 Xyz 987** for **765Xyz987** ,  **765 Xyz** for **765Xyz**, and **Xyz 987** for **Xyz987**. If possible a common command maybe? If not, separate command.

Comment: @OnePunchMan you can try `"765Xyz987".replaceAll("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)"," ")` that means any non-digit followed by digit or any digit followed by non-digit