# Converting string to readable SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am trying to add spaces to a string so that I can use it for `SimpleDateFormat`. I would need to add spaces to this:

```
String str = "Wed 3Jun15 03:22:15 pm"
```

I know how to put it into `SimpleDateFormat` as soon as I get it into this format:

```
String str = "Wed 3 Jun 15 03:22:15 pm"
```

Eventually I am only trying to pull `d, HH:mm` out of this date, so the rest can be trashed.

I have looked at this link: [How to split a string between letters and digits (or between digits and letters)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270784/how-to-split-a-string-between-letters-and-digits-or-between-digits-and-letters) and while it is closed, it doesn't work for what I am trying to do.

Comment: What did you tied? Give code snippet.

Comment: @Christopher You don't need to manipulate the String, just change the pattern to match it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pattern should match your string:

```
EEE dMMMyy hh:mm:ss a
```

With your example:

```
String str = "Wed 3Jun15 03:22:15 pm";
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE ddMMMyy hh:mm:ss a");
Date d = fmt.parse(str);
SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("d, HH:mm");
System.out.println(output.format(d)); //prints 3, 15:22
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I knew it had to do with the string matching, but I just couldn't seem to get it right. Thanks! Only issue is that, the `fmt.parse(str)` line requires you to throw an exception, which is easy enough to do. Thanks!!

Comment: minor follow-up question, this wouldn't work if the date went to double digits, for example `String str = "Wed 22Jun15 03:22:15 pm"` how would you counter for that? Youd have to make some sort of case statement for both, right? @assylias

Comment: Mmmm you are right I didn't think of that... See my edit (using `ddMMMyy` instead of `dMMMyy`).

Comment: yeah, i was just about to say that changing it to `..dd..` works. Thanks.