# How to split a number and a word which are altogether (as: 5John, 12Annie, 32Oliver) and prints them separately

Tags: java, jframe, clipboard

EDIT:I have a jFrame with a jLabel and a jTextField and a jButton.

jLabel:---> which shows the "Author ID" which is auto incrementing 1 by 1.

jTextField:---> user to enter the "Author Name"

jButton:---> when pressing it, it will copy the jLabel Text(auto incremented "Author ID") and the text in jTextField(which has Author Name entered by the user) into the System Clipboard as below and the jFrame will dispose after clicking the jButton.

This is the code where the Texts from jLabel and jTextfield will copy
into the System Clipboard.

```
    String authorId = jLabel2.getText();
    String authorName = jTextField1.getText();

    String both = authorId + authorName;

    StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(both);

    Clipboard clpbrd = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    clpbrd.setContents(stringSelection, null);

    this.dispose();
```

if we print the clipboard text at different intervals when user is entering the Names on jTextfield, it will prints as:

1John, 2Nick, 3Harold,............,25Sarah,.......,104Marie,..... and so on

But I'm unable to split the numbers and the Word(Name) and prints them separately. I tried this but it didn't work.

```
try {
       String data =(String)Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
       System.out.println(data);

} catch (UnsupportedFlavorException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(FindAuthor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (IOException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(FindAuthor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            }
```

I need to split the Number and Word and take prints them separately.

Comment: Upvoted. This is *so* easy to do in C. I guess Java is a case of one step forward and two steps back.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/8270824/5395773

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270784/how-to-split-a-string-between-letters-and-digits-or-between-digits-and-letters

Comment: Thanks Guys @Venkat

Comment: and @ManuelMejias :)

Comment: Basically: Use Regular expressions with `String.split()`

Comment: Why are you concatenating the ID and the name in the first place in `String both = authorId + authorName;` when later you need them separately? Seems to me to overcomplicate things.

Comment: @OleV.V. when it comes to pasting the Author Id and Author name in different jlabels, clipboard won't keep in memory those two as a Two, but as a whole(one)

Answer (score 1):

you can use regex, for example:

```
    String example = "104Marie";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)(\\w+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(example);

    if (m.find()) {
        // id
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
        // name
        System.out.println(m.group(2));
    }
```