# How can i split up an ArrayList of strings between letters and numbers WITHOUT using the split method?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, split, sublist

To take an arraylist of strings consisting of strings like:

```
fewf5677
kskfj654
pqoen444
mgnwo888
```

And i want to split them up BUT i DON'T want to use the split method because I have to perform other calculations with the letters that i'have split up.

SO i'have decided to use the `subList` method. But I can't seem to find a proper example of implementing this correctly. Take a look at my code. Below is a method that takes in an arraylist of strings as the parameter:

```
public static void splitup(ArrayList<String> mystrings){ 
     mystrings.subList(String[] letters, double numbers);
}
```

So overall, how do I take each string of letters and numbers and store them into their own string arrays? For example, i want

```
fewf
kskfj
pqoen
mgnwo
```

to be in their own string along with

```
5677
654
444
888
```

to be their own numbers.

Comment: Does the strings start always with letters and end with numbers?

Comment: What `mystrings.subList(String[] letters, double numbers);` should do in your intention? subList signature is the following `public List<E> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)`, only accepting int as input parameters...

Comment: yes. always. but the letter and number quantity is never defined. so for example i could have a string that's "abc123" and "helloeveryoneilovepie987654321" within this ArrayList of strings.

Comment: @salvolds so i can't split them up using subList?

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex as seen in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8270824/2180785) and then check for a pattern as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8270914/2180785) as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class StringSplitter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> myStringsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> stringsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> numbersList = new ArrayList<String>();

        myStringsList.add("fewf5677");
        myStringsList.add("kskfj654");
        myStringsList.add("pqoen444");
        myStringsList.add("mgnwo888");

        for (String s : myStringsList) {
            String splittedString[] = s.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)");

            for (String string : splittedString) {
                Matcher match = Pattern.compile("[0-9]").matcher(string);
                if (match.find()) {
                    numbersList.add(string);
                } else {
                    stringsList.add(string);
                }
            }
        }

        for (String s : numbersList) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        for (String s : stringsList) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

This will output:

```
5677
654
444
888
fewf
kskfj
pqoen
mgnwo
```

Remember that [`split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) takes a regex as parameter, not a `String` and so, you can do something like the above code to get the desired output.

Comment: Does this run in O(n) or O(n^2) runtime?

Comment: I don't know how to measure that time, but you can do it yourself if you want. Otherwise you can try to improve it

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is a bit strange. Why are you trying to overload subList method?

One of possible examples of what you could do is to iterate over `mystrings` list and separate each string into two variables. 
http://crunchify.com/how-to-iterate-through-java-list-4-way-to-iterate-through-loop/

If you are familiar with regular expressions you can use them them.

If not you can iterate over string characters to separate letters from number. 
http://java11s.blogspot.com/2012/02/java-program-to-separate-alphabets-and.html

Then add result to two separate lists `List<String>` and `List<Double>` (or probably `List<Integers>`) or create custom data structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way :

If we consider that the format of your input is a **String** in which you want to extract integers, then you should to test one element by one:

**Main**

```
public static void main(String[] a) {
    List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    myList.add("fewf5677");
    myList.add("kskfj654");
    myList.add("pqoen444");
    myList.add("mgnwo888");

    List<String> listStrings = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> listIntegers = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
        listStrings.add(getStringPart(myList.get(i)));
        listIntegers.add(Integer.parseInt(getIntegerPart(myList.get(i))));
    }

    System.out.println(listStrings);
    System.out.println(listIntegers);

}
```

**Get the string part of your element**

```
private static String getStringPart(String str) {
    String s = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (!testInteger(str.charAt(i))) {
            s += str.charAt(i);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

**Get the Integer part of your element**

```
private static String getIntegerPart(String str) {
    String s = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (testInteger(str.charAt(i))) {
            s += str.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

**A method to check if your str is and Integer or not**

```
private static boolean testInteger(char str) {
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(str+"");
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
[fewf, kskfj, pqoen, mgnwo]
[5677, 654, 444, 888]
```

Hope this can help you.