# javascript ; regex split string with number + rest of the string till next number

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I checked all the post and could not find correct solution so asking this question.

I have a string like " 3 rolls 7 buns 9 bars 7 cooks" and output that i am looking for is something like ["3 rolls","7 buns","9 bars","7 cooks"]

thanks.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of what you already tried

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270784/how-to-split-a-string-between-letters-and-digits-or-between-digits-and-letters Have you referred this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `regular expression` to achieve this,

```
var result = "3 rolls 7 buns 9 bars 7 cooks".split(/\s(?=\d)/);
conosole.log(result); //["3 rolls", "7 buns", "9 bars", "7 cooks"]
```

The regex concept used here is `positive look ahead`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.prototype.match()` with `RegExp` `/\d+\s+\w+/g` to match one or more digit characters followed by one or more space characters followed by one or more word characters

```js
var str = "3 rolls 7 buns 9 bars 7 cooks";
var res = str.match(/\d+\s+\w+/g);
console.log(res);
```