# How to split String for a digit and letters in java

Tags: java, string, split

Test data are e.g.

```
1a, 12a, 1ab, 12ab, 123a, 123abc
```

so if as input we have:

```
String input = "1a";
```

The output will be

```
String number = "1";
String letter = "a";
```

Like you can notice in this String there are sometimes 1-3digits(0-9) and sometimes 1-3letters(A-Z).

My first attempt:

I tried to use `.substring()`

But it will work only if there would've been for example always the same amount of digits or letters

My second attempt was:

```
.split(" ");
```

But it will work only if there will be a space or any other sign between.

PS.
Thanks for a response in answers. I checked most of your answers and they all work.
The question now which one is the best?

Comment: your string will always in the format of digits and then letters?

Comment: mention sample output for given strings in questions

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270784/how-to-split-a-string-between-letters-and-digits-or-between-digits-and-letters I think this will help you

Comment: Sample output will be for 1a first =1; second =a; (I'll update a question in a minute)

Comment: plz check the link mention above and let me know about results

Comment: Yeah, it helped me out and it worked well, but ppl answered with so many answers that right now I don't know which one is the best.

Comment: Try them and pick the one that works for you and that you will use. I think they pretty much all work

Comment: @degath you can find answer which is best suitaible to you according to your need

Comment: @degath try to find out answer which will have minimal execution time with optimize code with minimal comparison

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution without regular expressions:
Find the index of the first Letter and split the string at this position.

```
private String[] splitString(String s) {
  // returns an OptionalInt with the value of the index of the first Letter
  OptionalInt firstLetterIndex = IntStream.range(0, s.length())
    .filter(i -> Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i)))
    .findFirst();

  // Default if there is no letter, only numbers
  String numbers = s;
  String letters = "";
  // if there are letters, split the string at the first letter
  if(firstLetterIndex.isPresent()) {
    numbers = s.substring(0, firstLetterIndex.getAsInt());
    letters = s.substring(firstLetterIndex.getAsInt());
  }

  return new String[] {numbers, letters};
}
```

Gives you:

```
splitString("123abc") 
returns ["123", "abc"]

splitString("123") 
returns ["123", ""]

splitString("abc") 
returns ["", "abc"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
If your string sequence starts with digits and ends with letters, then the below code will work.


int asciRepresentation, startCharIndex = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        asciRepresentation = (int) str.charAt(i);
        if (asciRepresentation > 47 && asciRepresentation < 58)
            strB.append(str.charAt(i));
        else {
            startCharIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(strB.toString());
    if (startCharIndex != -1)
        System.out.println(str.substring(startCharIndex, str.length()));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex:

```
String str = "1a, 12a, 1ab, 12ab, 123a, 123abc";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<digit>\\d{1,3})(?<letter>[a-z]{1,3})");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

while (m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group("digit")+"/"+m.group("letter"));
}
// Ouput:
// 1/a
// 12/a
// 1/ab...
```

Answer (score 1):

Below you have my proposal. Works correctly for mentioned test data

(*1a, 12a, 1ab, 12ab, 123a, 123abc*)

**Solution:**

```
public ArrayList<String> split(String text) {

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)([a-zA-Z]+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

if (matcher.find() && matcher.groupCount() == 2) {
  result.add(matcher.group(1));
  result.add(matcher.group(2));
}
return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Solution:

(also take a look at the edit that I made at the end of my answer)

```
"\\b(\\d{1,3})([a-z]{1,3})(?=,*|\\b)"
```

### Example:

```
String s = "1a, 12a, 1ab, 12ab, 123a, 123abc";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b(\\d{1,3})([a-z]{1,3})(?=,*|\\b)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Group: "+ m.group() + ", letters: " + m.group(1) + ", digits: " + m.group(2));
}
```

Output that you get:

```
Group: 1a, letters: 1, digits: a
Group: 12a, letters: 12, digits: a
Group: 1ab, letters: 1, digits: ab
Group: 12ab, letters: 12, digits: ab
Group: 123a, letters: 123, digits: a
Group: 123abc, letters: 123, digits: abc
```

### Explanation:

`\\b(\\d{1,3})([a-z]{1,3})(?=,*|\\b)` whole regex

`\\b` - word boundary

`\\d{1,3}` - digit, from one to three times

`[a-z]{1,3}` - characters from `a` to `z` from one to three times

`(?=,*|\\b)` - this is positive lookahead, you say that after these letters you want to be present `,` or word boundary, but you don't want them to be present in the matching group (called with `m.group()`)

`()` - matching groups are in parenthesis - in my regex I used two matching groups: #1: `(\\d{1,3})` #2: `([a-z]{1,3})` (they are printed with `m.group(1)` and `m.group(2)`)

If you're not very familiar to regular expressions syntax yet, you might want to have a look at Java API Documentation of [class Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). There is a list of available uses of regular expressions. It's worth giving regular expressions a try, as it might save a lot of your time when working with Strings in the future.

---

### Edit:

Actually this regex can be changed to:

`(?<=\\b)(\\d{1,3})([a-z]{1,3})(?=\\b)`

There is a positive lookbehind `(?<=\\b)` - it means that you want digits to preceded by word boundary (including commas in the lookahead and lookbehind was redundant so I deleted it).

Comment: You write exactly my solution but 20 minutes later

Comment: @ThibautB. Yeah now when I look at your answer, it's similar, but written in other "words". Anyway, now I improved my answer to better cover OP's expectations and now our answers are not very similar. Thanks for pointing it out, I haven't looked at your answer when writing my own.

Comment: Thanks for the change, I'm not a fan of plagiarism :p

Comment: @ThibautB. I'm far from plagiarizing answers of others here at Stack Overflow or in any other situation anywhere.

Comment: No problem, it was a joke, look my smiley at the end ;). I just notice you that you hadn't read answers before posting.